# BinHex 4.0 decoder to use in commercial software

Tags: c++

I am looking for code or library I can use in commercial software to decode binhex 4.0 files (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BinHex).

After searching web I found these:

- Several copies C code that is seems to be widely used (https://www.mpp.mpg.de/~huber/vmssig/src/C/XBIN.C) but it requires obtaining permission from Brown University.
- Python code (part of python distribution) with not very assuring comments like "I don't understand what happens when you get 0x90 times the same byte on input." and near 0 unit tests.
- Java code on github.com/aviyam without any license, but also no unit tests and 0 issues reported.

I would prefer something I could use in C++ running on Windows, but after all searching and not finding much I am fine with any code that is well tested (i.e. has unit tests or a large set of binhex files).

Thank you!